# WiFi On Deepin Linux 15.11

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

Im new to this distro and i've recently installed deepin on acer nitro 5 laptop. Everything seems perfect except WiFi. In the network tab. I cant even see the wireless network option. I ve intel wifi 6 200 160mhz adapter in my laptop. Can anyone guide me to fix this since i am newbie ? Already ive tried almost tens of tutorials but nothing helped at all.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Please share *what* you already tried, this helps people figure out other alternatives.

Comment: Deepin Support may have a solution for you as well; see https://bbs.deepin.org/forum.php?mod=forumdisplay&fid=70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly Updating The Kernal Fixed The Solution.

Found The Article Saying These Modern  Wifi Interfaces Needs 5.1 Up Kernal Version To Work